# How would you draw $(A\setminus B)\times (A\setminus B) = (A\times A)\setminus (B\times B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, visualization

I know it's useful to prove set equalities to make a quick sketch of the sets described. How can I draw this one?

$$(A\setminus B)\times (A\setminus B) = (A\times A)\setminus (B\times B)$$

Comment: Unless you have a special talent for drawing, I don't think this one can be easily drawn.

Comment: I'm really not a fan of drawing things like this, but if it helps to get your head around it, try drawing a few intervals $A$ and $B$ on the $x$ axis of the plane, drawing the same ones in the $y$-axis, then drawing the products from your equation.

Comment: What Timbuc wanted to say is that you cannot draw this because this is not true.

Comment: It's not true, but you can draw the sets on both sides of the equations to get an idea of how they differ, it's not a proof but it might set you in the right direction.

Comment: If $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$, then $(3,1)\in (A\times A)\setminus (B\times B)$, but $(3,1)\notin (A\setminus B)\times (A\setminus B)$

Answer (score 1):

Usually $\blacksquare_1 \neq  \blacksquare_2 \setminus \blacksquare_3$.

Comment: Cartesian product of two sets in some sense is similar to a square.